# How to add searchable choice field in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am looking for implementing searchable choice field (searchable dropdown) in django using django forms and models.

This choice field will be populated from database.

Comment: Take a look at third party libraries, such as `django-select2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be easily done only with Django, check this [list of Django packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/) that implement the AutoCompletable feature.

I have used and I personally recommend you [Django Autocomplete Light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: Django Autocomplete Light is really very good. Thanks!

Comment: I have implemented django-autocomplete-light widget. Can you let me know how to get name of months instead of number. Also, can we set default values of month and year          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604975/django-django-yearmonth-widget-display-month-as-month-name

Comment: I have opened a new question in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604975/django-django-yearmonth-widget-display-month-as-month-name