# django django-yearmonth-widget display month as month name

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-widget

I have used package "django-yearmonth-widget" to have year and month selection and not complete date. Here, day is fixed i.e. 1st of every month. This implementation is working fine.

Package:

```
pip install django-yearmonth-widget
```

Problem I am facing is for field "**file_upload_datetime**" and describe as below

1. How to display month as month name and not number
2. display Option 0 as --Year-- and --Month-- or something like --Select--
3. Give proper label to the field

Forms

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(required=True,widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}), label='Select Files')
    file_remote = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}), required=False)
    class Meta():
        model = FileUpload
        fields= ('file_upload_datetime','file','file_remote')
        widgets = {
            'file_upload_datetime': DjangoYearMonthWidget(),
            'file_remote':forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

Models

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    file_remote = models.FileField(upload_to=RetailFormsConfig.remote_folder, storage=upload_storage, blank=True)
    file_upload_datetime = models.DateField()
```

Inside view, I access month and year as date as below

```
file_upload_datetime = file_upload_form.cleaned_data['file_upload_datetime']
```

Please refer below screenshots for reference

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please provide these. People need your code to understand what is going on.

Comment: Added code. Sorry I missed to add necessary code

Comment: @Ronak did you eventually get to display the month as names?

Comment: @pragMATHiC - Yes, but i had to do the same using javascript. Adding javascript code snippet above

Answer (score 0):

Displayed Month name using below code snippet in javascript

```
list = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
$("select.django-yearmonth-widget-month-selector").empty().populate(list);
$("select.django-yearmonth-widget-month-selector")
  .val(current_date.getMonth() + 1) //month starting from 0
  .change();
```